# HTML Table Creation

Tags: html

I want to create a table like shown in the image using HTML. How to do?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

User `colspan="3"` attribute if you need marge two cells into one .
[w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_colspan.asp)

```css
th, td {
  background: #ddd;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>&nbsp;</th>
    <th>9AM</th>
    <th>10AM</th>
    <th>11AM</th>
    <th>12AM</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mon day</td>
    <td colspan="2">1</td>
    <td>2</td>
    <td>3</td>

  </tr>


  <tr>
    <td>tuesDay</td>
    <td scope="col" colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
    <!-- The following two cells will appear under the same header -->
    <td>Col 1</td>

  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Actually, I need the exact table shown in the image.

Comment: @MelbinMathai, **SO** is not a code writing service. You can refer the example given in answer and write your own code to match with your requirements.

Comment: @niyasc I am already did everything. But the problem is, how to give a spacing between the row and column like in the image?

Comment: @yugi This was fine.  But the problem is, how to give a spacing between the row and column like in the image? Thank you.

Comment: @MelbinMathai user `cellpadding`  if need space between cells